# add plugin components in migration script cakephp 3.0

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins, migration, cakephp-3.0

I am working on a migrations script and need to call a function which is inside a Component in a plugin.
How can I do it?

I tried adding it to $components array which would obviously not have worked.

```
$components=['PluginName.ComponentName'];
```

Comment: Why Do you need to use a Component method inside a migration?

Comment: If you have a method in a component that is required by a migration then it is in the wrong place. Migrations should have no need to call Controller logic.

Comment: Migrations should not depend on any logic implemented in the App at all, not even table instances. This will screw up data in the worst case due to attached behaviors causing unwanted changes for example.

Comment: I need to make schema changes in several databases. It runs in the application just fine. I wanted to use the function in migrations so that any other adaptation of the site would help requires them to run the migration script

Answer (score 0):

Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers.

If you need to use a external method inside a migration, it should be inside a `Table` or `Entity` related to the `migration`, or even inside a `Trait`.

See:

- [Components](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components.html)
- [Migrations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/migrations.html)
- [Traits](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.traits.php)